# Synchronize iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I would like to synchronize multiple iframes. I.e. if I make a change in one iframe the result should be displayed in all other frames.

Background:
I want to show the display on different display sizes in parallel.

However, I now have a cyclic call. Each action changes the URL of the current page. I want to display this URL in the other iframes.

**HTML code**

```
<div>
    <h3>local display landscape</h3>
    <iframe id="iframe_unit_landscape" name="iframe_unit_landscape" onload="loadIFrame(0)"
        src="http://localhost:3000/mainmenu.html" height="240" width="320" class="iframe">
    </iframe>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>local display portrait</h3>
    <iframe id="iframe_unit_portrait" name="iframe_unit_portrait" onload="loadIFrame(1)"
        src="http://localhost:3000/mainmenu.html" height="320" width="240" class="iframe">
    </iframe>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>iPhone 8 landscape</h3>
    <iframe id="iframe_iphone8_landscape" name="iframe_iphone8_landscape" onload="loadIFrame(2)"
        src="http://localhost:3000/mainmenu.html" height="375" width="667" class="iframe">
    </iframe>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>iPhone 8 portrait</h3>
    <iframe id="iframe_iphone8_portrait" name="iframe_iphone8_portrait" onload="loadIFrame(3)"
        src="http://localhost:3000/mainmenu.html" height="667" width="375" class="iframe">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

**JS code**

```
<script>
const iframes = ['iframe_unit_landscape', 'iframe_unit_portrait', 'iframe_iphone8_landscape', 'iframe_iphone8_portrait'];

function loadIFrame(id) {
    let iframe = document.getElementById(iframes[id]); 

    for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
        if (i !== iframe) {
           var dest = document.getElementById(iframes[i]).src = src;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Of course this runs in circles, because when you are setting the new URL for one of those iframes, this triggers the `onload` handler for that iframe again. Which will then make that iframe, trigger a change of all the others again … You would first of all need to find a way to differentiate between an iframe loading something new, because you clicked a link inside of it (or whatever you consider “making changes”), and it being reloaded from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

So I added an `event listener` to all the `iframes`, on load the `iframes` array should be filtered to remove the frames without the same `src`, and set the `src`.

So whenever the filtered `iframes` load and run the function, there would be no other iframe without the same `src` preventing an infinite loop

```
const iframes = ['iframe_unit_landscape', 'iframe_unit_portrait', 'iframe_iphone8_landscape', 'iframe_iphone8_portrait'].map(id => document.getElementById(id));

iframes.forEach(iframe => iframe.addEventListener('load', _ => iframes.filter(frame => frame.src != iframe.src).forEach(frame => frame.src = iframe.src)));
```

---

```
<div>
  <h3>local display landscape</h3>
  <iframe id="iframe_unit_landscape" name="iframe_unit_landscape" src="http://localhost:3000/mainmenu.html" height="240" width="320" class="iframe"></iframe>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>local display portrait</h3>
  <iframe id="iframe_unit_portrait" name="iframe_unit_portrait" src="http://localhost:3000/mainmenu.html" height="320" width="240" class="iframe"></iframe>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>iPhone 8 landscape</h3>
  <iframe id="iframe_iphone8_landscape" name="iframe_iphone8_landscape" src="http://localhost:3000/mainmenu.html" height="375" width="667" class="iframe"></iframe>
</div>
<div>
  <h3>iPhone 8 portrait</h3>
  <iframe id="iframe_iphone8_portrait" name="iframe_iphone8_portrait" src="http://localhost:3000/mainmenu.html" height="667" width="375" class="iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```